# Get Firebase database file donwloadURL manually - iOS platform

Tags: ios, firebase-realtime-database

I know if I upload an image file to Firebase Database via `putData` method.  In return, I can get the `downloadURL` from `metadata`.

But what if I do not want to store this `downloadURL`.  And later, I want to download this image.

Question:  Can I get this downloadURL if I know the image's file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the file name (or really: the file path) of the image in Firebase Storage, you can get the download URL using:

```
// Create a reference to the file you want to download
let starsRef = storageRef.child("images/stars.jpg")
// Fetch the download URL
starsRef.downloadURLWithCompletion { (URL, error) -> Void in
  if (error != nil) {
    // Handle any errors
  } else {
    // Get the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'
  }
}
```

See the [Firebase Storage documentation on downloading files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#create_a_reference) from where I got the above example.

Comment: Indeed it is the one!